# Corte de control c# winform

Tags: c#

Cordial saludo a todo el que lea esta consulta!!

necesito ayuda para realizar un corte de control en c# con los siguientes datos

FORD;KA;3

FORD;FIESTA;5

FORD;MONDEO,8

RENAULT;DUSTER;7

RENAULT;SANDERO;7

VOLKSWAGEN;SURAN;6

tengo un codigo hecho pero no cumple con dicho corte de control
lo pasaria pero no se como y me acaban de eliminar esta misma pregunta hace unos minutos

Comment: nadie elimino la pregunta. fue cerrada por ambigua, porque no tenia codigo ni nada. Ya se vuelve a abrir. por favor lee los enlaces que te pasaron en la anterior, hacer una nueva solo provoca que cerremos la nueva.. si se cerro una, es por algo, es porque hay que mejorarla...